# Can I create a restricted user on a linux server?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users

I've setup a Webserver with a GIT branching model. Now I want to create something like a technical user on my server. This user should not have an own account (I just need the user to to execute `git *, and cd` commands).

If this is possible, can you teach me how I can:

- create a technical user?
- limit this user to only `git *` and `cd` commands?

If I can't create something like a technical user, what would be the best way to create a user that only should be allowed to perform `git` and `cd` commands?

Currently I'm working with the root user which is not what I want for the future.

If it's possible to create this user, how I can change the directory owner to another user so that the technical user don't gets the owner of any file or folder?

Comment: How is a "technical user" different from a "user"?

Comment: Thats why I'm asking this question, to clarify, if there are technical users which are only there to perform commands like git add . or git commit -m

Comment: That's just a user with a restricted shell. Not a "technical user"

Comment: you can create a technical user with `useradd -m technical`. Seriously, any moderately "technical" user will have no trouble to get out of `git` and do everything she wants (first thing I can think of: run `git log`, and in the pager press `!bash`).

Comment: Please edit question to make it clear: What does the user need to be able to do? What should they not be able to do? (don't say run git. What do they need to do? What goals do they have?)